# CE Fonts in iText

Tags: java, unicode, itext7

I need to write a program that generates pdf's in czech.
I'm almost finished, but i got some characters that don't appear on my pdf's.

Unsurprisingly theyre all specific czech chars like "Č".
I tried to implement a CE Font, which contains the char "Č", but even with this font the letters don't show up, on the pdf it looks like an empty String.

I tried the Helvetica CE and DejaVuSansMono-Oblique. I got the "Č" in both, if you can trust the software FontForge, with the unicode "\u010c" which is the one my Java Application is putting out when I **System.out.println(String.format("\u%04x", (int) c));**  (c = Č).

Is anyone having expierience with something like this?

Edit:

The Style changes, but the letters, which should now show up, are still missing.

My code,

```
FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont("C:\\DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf");
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontProgram, PdfEncodings.WINANSI, false);
paragraph.setFont(font);
```

Comment: probably best if you share the code you're trying to use

Comment: Hi André,
Im afraid I cant get my code in an answere in a proper format.
Can you tell me how I can show you my code in the best way?
Is there a better possibility to post my code than in an answere?

Comment: you should edit your question, and add the code there

Comment: `PdfEncodings.WINANSI` is an encoding similar to Latin-1, so it most likely cannot encode your special characters. Try an **Identity-H** encoding.

Answer (score 1):

That worked for me!

> `PdfEncodings.WINANSI` is an encoding similar to Latin-1, so it most likely cannot
> encode your special characters. Try an **Identity-H** encoding. – mkl